# Can I scpecify or get Abjad (v3.2) output PDF file's path or name after creating it?

Tags: python, pdf, flask, metadata, lilypond

I have a flask server that generates musical PDFs with abjad v3.2.

After using `abjad.show()`, I would like to get the path to the created file.
I can get the output directory, by using `abjad.Configuration().abjad_output_directory` but not the specific file I created.

My question is how can I get the path to the file (not the folder but the specific file) I just created in order to send it back to the user?

My python code that creates the PDF file:

```
staff = abjad.Staff(abjad_notes)

# attach BPM to notes file
metronome_mark = abjad.MetronomeMark((1, 4), bpm)
abjad.attach(metronome_mark, staff[0])

# creates lilypond file object
lilypond_file = abjad.LilyPondFile.new(staff)

# notes title
lilypond_file.header_block.title = abjad.Markup(title)

# show PDF on screen
abjad.show(lilypond_file)
```

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful to you, but you can use `abjad.PersistenceManager` to manually set the output path of the `.ly` and `.pdf` files generated by Abjad (as opposed to letting Abjad create them in the folder `~/.abjad/output`). Here is an example of how to use it: after creating your `lilypond_file` variable, use it as `abjad.PersistenceManager(lilypond_file).as_pdf('~/output_score.pdf')`. If this helps, let me know and I can write it as a proper answer instead of as a comment.

Comment: @gilbertohasnofb It worked, thanks a lot. But I do have something to add. Your code was for abjad 3.0. In v3.2, it should like ```abjad.persist.as_pdf(lilypond_file, "/path/to/file.pdf")```. It helped me and served my needs, appreciate it!

Comment: yeah, unfortunately Abjad tends to have very poor backward compatibility, they keep renaming functions and classes so it's always tricky. I still haven't upgrade from 3.1 as I am in the middle of some projects at the moment. I will create an answer reflecting these things now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Abjad 3.2, you can use `abjad.persist` to manually set the output path of the `.ly` and `.pdf` files generated by Abjad (as opposed to letting Abjad create them in the default folder `~/.abjad/output`).

To use it, first create a `lilypond_file` variable which instantiates `abjad.LilyPondFile` and then use it as `abjad.persist.as_pdf(lilypond_file, '/path/to/file.pdf')`. In your minimal example above, this becomes:

```
staff = abjad.Staff(abjad_notes)

# attach BPM to notes file
metronome_mark = abjad.MetronomeMark((1, 4), bpm)
abjad.attach(metronome_mark, staff[0])

# creates lilypond file object
lilypond_file = abjad.LilyPondFile.new(staff)

# notes title
lilypond_file.header_block.title = abjad.Markup(title)

# save pdf file at a custom location
abjad.persist.as_pdf(lilypond_file, '/path/to/file.pdf')
```